# Do python pandas sparse dataframes lose multi-index column names or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: python, pandas

I just want to see if anybody can see an error in what I'm doing before I go and open an issue...

Minimal example - first create a multi-index dataframe:

```
miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["x","y"], ["10","20"]],names=['row-foo', 'row-bar'])    
micol = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b','c'], ["1","2"]],names=['col-foo', 'col-bar'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=miindex, columns=micol).sortlevel().sortlevel(axis=1)
df = df.fillna(value=3.14) 
df
```

This gives us a nice test multi-index with column and row level names:

[image: Python multi-index with valid column level names]

Now if I make a sparse matrix out of that and show it, the column level names are gone:

```
ds = df.to_sparse()
ds
```

[image: Python sparse multi-index with missing column level names]

And if I convert the sparse version back to dense those level names are still gone:

```
tf = ds.to_dense()
tf
```

[image: Python dense multi-index with missing column level names]

Now I AM aware that displaying the sparse version calls to_dense() but the loss appears to be happening at the conversion to sparse. I'm exploring moving to sparse to reduce memory usage for a code base and my attempts to access the levels within the sparse dataframe generate "KeyError: 'Level  not found'"

Anyone know how to preserve column level names in a pandas sparse dataframe?

(Tests shown on pandas 0.17.0, also observed on 0.16.2)

Comment: Looks like a bug, please file an issue on github.

Comment: Will do! (when back at my desk) Thanks!

Comment: @AndyHayden - bug reported, Jeff said sparse doesn't get much attention so I put together fix code myself and it's been merged to master. Thanks for the sanity check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in pandas.

Issue tracker here:https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11600

Pull request sent and fix code merged to master

Looks like fix will be in 0.17.1